# Leveraging HTML5 input validation in other code

Tags: javascript, forms, html, validation

Suppose I have some Javascript in which I need to validate email addresses, dates, etc. in strings that I obtain from an API call.

HTML5 has this capability built in for `input` fields, and I'd like piggyback on that implementation instead of using regex or an external library - but in a way that's invisible to end users.

My code pattern for this right now would be to:

- Create a form with an invisible `input` field element of the desired type
- fill the `input` element with the string
- Call `checkValidity()` on the element

Is there a better solution? If not, would any implementation of the above pattern offer significant advantages?

*Note: I don't have any code to show for this - it's (currently) a hypothetical question.*

Comment: I wonder if this library uses this approach already: http://jquerytools.org/documentation/validator/index.html

Comment: No; that also validates fields, rather than plain strings.